# Is it okay to submit bug reports and feedback here about the iOS app, even though it's not being developed?

Tags: discussion, ios-app, meta

It seems that every iOS app feedback submission here is met with a reminder that the Stack Exchange iOS app isn't currently being worked on. Is it okay to make submissions here about the app anyway, assuming that the app will one day be revisited and the feedback might be useful?